# autostart application using raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to autostart my application. I have used "Method 1" of the following link as reference http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/ everything works fine. The application autostarts but after 10 seconds it crashes. unable to find a solution. please help

Comment: What happens when the program crashes? Are there any particular error messages displayed? Have you tried launching the program manually?

Comment: yea manually its running fine. no error messages displayed. just crashes

Comment: You can try to debug it by redirecting its logs to a files. For example, @your-application-path > /home/pi/app-log.txt Also, what are you trying to run ? Is it an application made by you or an existing app ?

Comment: its an application developed be me based on opencv C++